# Random no switch statement, por que não funciona?

Tags: c#

Seguindo o código abaixo, a minha intenção era randomizar o switch para escolher entre o case 1 e 2, após receber a palavra "gamble". Acontece que quando escrevo gamble, só é ativado o case 1 (somar 10 ferros), ao invés de ser aleatório entre somar 10 ou subtrair 10. O que fiz de errado ?

```
            int ferros;          
            string gamble;
            gamble = Console.ReadLine();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int luck = rnd.Next(1,3);
            bool loop = true;
            while (loop)
            {
              if (gamble == "gamble")
              {
                  switch (luck)
                  {
                    case 1:
                        ferros = ferros + 10;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ferros = ferros - 10;
                        break;
                  }
              }
            }
```

Comment: O código é só esse ou você simplificou? Se está testando num _loop_, tem que tirar o new Random() de dentro (usar uma instância só), senão pode ter uma inicialização com _seed_ repetido. Seria legal por a classe da forma que testou na realidade e explicar como fez pra executar.

Comment: Boa noite Bacco, eu realmente estava fazendo dentro de um loop, e o meu erro na verdade foi não colocar int rng = rnd.Next(1, 3); e gamble = Console.ReadLine(); dentro do loop. Acabei percebendo este erro após ler o seu comentário, mesmo sendo sem querer, foi de grande ajuda hahaha. E obrigado pela dica da seed repetida :)

Comment: Sugiro postar **no campo de respostas** o código resolvido explicando qual era o erro (e marcando sua resposta como aceita), ou remover a questão, só pra não largar pendente.

Comment: Já foi postado no campo de respostas, porém só é possível marcar a minha resposta como "aceita" após 2 dias.

Answer (score 3):

O erro foi não ter introduzido o "sistema" para randomizar dentro do loop. A resolução para o problema é implementar o gamble = Console.ReadLine(); e a váriavel int luck = rnd.Next(1,3); dentro do loop, para que o "sistema" de randomização seja sempre repetido.

```
        int ferros;          
        string gamble;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        bool loop = true;
        while (loop)
        {
         gamble = Console.ReadLine();
         int luck = rnd.Next(1,3);


            if (gamble == "gamble")
            {
              switch (luck)
              {
                case 1:
                    ferros = ferros + 10;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ferros = ferros - 10;
                    break;
              }
            }
        } //Code
```